# Búsqueda iterativa vector no ordenado

Tags: c++, loops, iteradores

Hice un ejercicio resuelto de búsqueda iterativa de un número en un vector no ordenado. Quería saber si el planteamiento está bien, ya que me encargo de compilar y corregir errores.

Este es el enunciado:

> Impleméntese  la  función iterativa template <> vector_t::BBR(int
>   i, int d, int x) const que    lleva   a   cabo la búsqueda de un  elemento    x
>   dentro    del vector  invocante,  en  los extremos    i y d del   vector

```
vector_t<int>::BBR(int i,int d,int x){
bool encontrado=false;

 for(int i=0;i<v_.get_sz();i++){
    if(v_[i]==x){
        encontrado=true;
    }
 }
return encontrado;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te están pidiendo que localices un elemento dentro de un rango, luego la iteración que haces es incorrecta. Tu estás buscando el elemento en toda la lista cuando deberías limitarte al rango:

```
for(;i<d;i++){
```

En principio este bucle permitiría buscar en posiciones que están fuera de la lista... pero en ningun sitio dice que tengas que comprobar que el rango sea correcto. Así pues procura no hacer algo como que:

```
vector.BBR(5,-1,-2);
```

Y, para rematar, tendría sentido abortar la búsqueda una vez has encontrado el elemento. Esto lo podrías hacer con break o con return... al gusto.

**opción break**

```
bool vector_t<int>::BBR(int i,int d,int x) const{
  bool encontrado=false;

  for(;i<d;i++){
    if(v_[i]==x){
      encontrado=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return encontrado;
}
```

**opción break implícito**

```
bool vector_t<int>::BBR(int i,int d,int x) const{
  bool encontrado=false;

  for(;i<d && !encontrado;i++){
    if(v_[i]==x){
      encontrado=true;
    }
  }
  return encontrado;
}
```

**opción return**

```
bool vector_t<int>::BBR(int i,int d,int x) const{

  for(;i<d;i++){
    if(v_[i]==x){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: el problema es que el enunciado dice: " Impleméntese la función iterativa template <> vector_t<int>::BBR(int i, int d, int x) const que lleva a cabo la búsqueda de un elemento x dentro del vector invocante, en los extremos i y d del vector" Entonces estoy obligado a usar i y d

Comment: Ese detalle se te ha olvidado comentarlo en la pregunta...

Comment: @AER por favor, edita la pregunta y añade esa información

Comment: ya edité la pregunta